# How to load icon font in p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I'm following a tutorial from code train to transform webcam image to ASCII text but i want to load my own font which is not working

https://editor.p5js.org/donnarikhof/sketches/OfA5yWCE7
this is a link to the sketch. you can see the webcam works but the font does not load (i have uploaded it to the file as well)

i tried the loadfont but does not seem to work.

```
let myFont;

function preload() {
  myFont = loadFont("NewFont-Regular.otf");
}
```

I have not used p5.js in a while so if someone knows how to help me out would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are just putting html text into a div, instead of drawing in the canvas.

So you can add the font using CSS

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src:  url("NewFont-Regular.otf") format('otf');
}

body {
   font-family: `MyWebFont`
}
```